# How can I use the Scala program schema2src?

Tags: scala, sbaz

This perhaps more a Server Fault question...

I installed `schema2src` via `sbaz` and now I would like to convert a DTD (Apple's plist schema) to Scala source.

```
$ schema2src
usage: 
  schema2src [flags] --module mname arg* 
or
  schema2src dtd arg* 
or (experimental)
  schema2src xsd arg* (this doesn't work at all yet)

where supported [flags] may be: 
  --verbose    prints some debugging information
```

However, if I try give *any* argument, it appears it can't find Scala:

```
$ schema2src --verbose
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/BoxesUtility
    at schema2src.Main$.processArgs(Main.scala:56)
    at schema2src.Main$.main(Main.scala:25)
    at schema2src.Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.runtime.BoxesUtility
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:315)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:330)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:250)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398)
    ... 3 more
```

I have `scala` in my `PATH`...

Any suggestions? Assuming that problem can be fixed, is this the correct syntax?

```
$ schema2src PropertyList-1.0.dtd
```

Comment: That's old code. Likely, you are using it with a much newer version of Scala than it was written in.

Comment: I'm interested in an answer to this question, too. I've been looking into this problem some months ago. Maybe someone will port it to 2.8 ;)

Comment: Ahh, bummer. And it looks like scalaxb uses 2.8 while I'm still on 2.7.7.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is now http://scalaxb.org/

Comment: Cool, thanks. Unfortunately that seems to be 2.8 only while I'm still at 2.7.7.